# 'Folder' already locked by 'Folder'

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, tortoisesvn

I have this very VERY annoying issue where I'm attempting to merge our trunk into my branch for some updates. I have been doing this on a daily basis but almost every single day I get the following error:

```
Error - 'D:\Code\Website' is already locked via 'D:\Code\Website'.
```

Only very randomly does this error not happen and I am able to successfully merge trunk back into the branch. However, all day I've been trying to get the latest from the trunk without success. I have looked high and low for answers to this issue.. SO, Google, random forums on the internet... etc. I'm hoping someone can shed some light on why this might be happening.

This is what I've already tried:

- Run "Clean up" on every single folder within the directory.
- Checked for "lock" file in .svn directory - doesn't exist.
- Opened wc.db file and checked WC_LOCK table - nothing in there.
- Disabled anti-virus.
- Disabled IIS.
- Checked out a fresh copy of the branch.
- Updated TortoiseSVN
- Completed uninstalled and re-installed TortoiseSVN with latest MSI from TortoiseSVN.net (1.7.10.23359, SVN 1.7.7).

I am able to Update the branch and Commit it.. there has never been an issue with that. It's just Merging trunk back in that is causing me issues. No one else on the team seems to have this problem (with this branch, or any others). They can freely check the branch out.. merge trunk in and commit it without issues.

I am using TortoiseSVN. Any help you guys/gals have would be fantastic!

EDIT: Also, a Test Merge works.. but an actual Merge doesn't.

**UPDATE**

It turns out TSVNCache.exe CONSTANTLY holds locks on the wc.db file. I have no idea why. Even if I kill the process; once I go through the TSVN Merge GUI it fires up the cache again and locks it. I have managed to successfully merge via the command line.. is there any way to fix the cache locking issue to avoid having to rely on the command line?

Comment: If it's really locked, what does "Show Locks" tell you? Are you using Eclipse with SVN connectors? Those, as my experience goes, tend to mess up your local WC.

Comment: No locks at all. The Release Lock dialog doesn't show anything. Visual Studio is my IDE and I don't have any SVN addons for it..

Comment: Ok. What about foreign locks? Someone else claiming this branch? There might be an issue with AnkhSVN. Is that what you're using as well?

Comment: Every other team member can merge into the branch though.. and they can also commit it (there's 10 of us.. of which I've had about 3 or 4 try it for me). Also, I don't have AnkhSVN installed.. I don't have any IDE addons for SVN.. I only have TortoiseSVN (the shell extensions).

Comment: If you merge using TSVN with files opened in VS - *it can be* reason for (side) locking. BTW, 'D:\Code\Website' is WC for what? How you merge (show command, pls)

Comment: Lock doesn't prohibit local merge, only commit. Thus - you have **NOT SVN LOCK**, but Windows lock (for open files?)

Comment: It turns out TSVNCache.exe CONSTANTLY holds locks on the wc.db file. I have no idea why. Even if I kill the process, if I go through the TSVN Merge GUI it fires up the cache again and locks it. I have managed to successfully merge via the command line.. is there any way to fix the cache locking issue?

Comment: run an update before the merge. The problem only occurs if you have a mixed-rev working copy.

Answer (score 8):

Try turning off the icon overlay status cache (What the TSVNcache.exe process is responsible for)

1. Open an Explorer Window
2. Right click anywhere, TortoiseSVN -> Settings
3. Go to the "Icon Overlays" section
4. Select the "None" radio button under Status Cache
5. Click Apply

Presumably if the status cache is disabled and TSVNcache.exe isn't running, then it can't lock any files. You can at least rule out whether this is the problem (it sure sounds like it is). This is the process that's responsible for updating the folder/file icons in Explorer with that green checkmark, red modified mark, and so forth. I've disabled this for performance reasons for years. I just view modified files or open a commit dialog to see what files have changed.

After that, the next most likely suspect is the Indexing service (Windows Search) from past experience.

Comment: I did this.. and now when I see a merge failing and run `handle` from sysinternals, I see `TortoiseProc.exe` locking it :/

Comment: I have, yes. At this stage I'll put it down to my PC just being annoying. Maybe I'll get a new PC out of it? :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Here is what I did:

1. Kill explorer.exe in Task Manager
2. Start it again from Task Manager
3. Now the merge works...

I guess somehow Windows Explorer can lock something.

Comment: I just closed the Explorer window and it worked for me (at least this time - I can see comments from other about continuous issues, this is what makes me biased towards Git).

Answer (score 2):

Another option that works for me instead of giving up the Icon Overlays, is to change directory in Windows Explorer to a non-svn folder and this way TortoiseSVN does not conflict with itself. It is so annoying but if you need a quick solution - this is it.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem for some time now. Especially since my repositories are growing hard.

The pointer that TSVNCache locks the working copy got me thinking. Why would it do that? Conclusion: only when it is busy updating the working copy status (including icon overlays).

One way to overcome this problem is exactly what Joshua McKinnon says: disabling icon overlays. If that is not the solution you want (because you want to keep the icons) you can also go for a different approach: wait till the TSVNCache has finished doing its job. When you open the merge window you can see TSVNCache being busy (in a process explorer). When that busyness is over it is safe to do the merge. No more locking problems since then!